# SpringBoot 3 without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 3 without WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter. following as the code. But .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll(); it give error. Screen Shot Attached.

1. I want to allow  "/api/auth/**".
2. authorizeRequests() seems deprecated in SpringBoot 3. Any alternative ???
3. @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true) also seems deprecated. any new solution.
   [image]

thanks in advance.

[image]

```
package com.example.tokenAuth.security;

import com.example.tokenAuth.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.example.tokenAuth.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.tokenAuth.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig 
{
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService; 
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() 
    {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }    
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() 
    {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   
      return authProvider;
    }    
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfiguration) throws Exception 
    {
        return authConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }    
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll();
//                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
               // .anyRequest().authenticated();
                http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
                 
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() 
    {
        return (web) -> web.debug(true).ignoring().anyRequest();
    }    

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
    {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Example is taken from:https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/

Comment: So you take an example with an older version and are surprised said sample doesn't work on a newer version. For the deprecations I strongly suggest the documentation of the deprecated methods/annotations as those explain clearly what the replacements are.

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to first upgrade to Spring Security 5.8, fix the deprecations, and upgrade to 6.0.

Please refer to the [`Preparing to 6.0` guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html) from Spring Security.

1. `antMatchers`, `mvcMatchers`, `regexMatchers` have been replaced by `requestMatchers`, [see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11939).
2. `authorizeHttpRequests()` in the recommended method since 5.6, [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html).
3. `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` has been superseded by `@EnableMethodSecurity`, [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#_enablemethodsecurity).

All those changes are in the method's javadoc deprecation notice as well.

[Spring Security 6.0.0-RC1 changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/6.0.0-RC1)